# jquery stop event bubbling with live

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
 var input = $("form input[name='name'].dhxlist_txt_textarea");

 $(input).live('click', function () {

       ShowLookupGrid();
 });
```

Then I've putted a second live binding before the first get executed

```
  $('#Id').live('click', function () {

       return false;
 });
```

But the return false statement isn't stoping bubbling up the event to the second binding.

Comment: there is no connection between first and second event(click), then how does it stop??

Comment: there is one input with the used Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should stop any other events of the same type being fired on that element as long as it is the first event handler that is run.

```
$('#Id').live('click', function (event) {
   event.stopImmediatePropagation()
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/f6WUr/1/)

Comment: Since the `.live()` method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of live events.  reference: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

Comment: @diEcho Although the API says that my jsfiddle test does appear to work. I would guess because .live() binds all the events at the same level it's still possible to prevent other events being fired.

Answer (score 1):

This is not event bubbling, you are attaching a handler twice to the same element (one through the id selector and other one through element selector).

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) written clearly

> Since the .live() method handles
>   events once they have propagated to
>   the top of the document, it is not
>   possible to stop propagation of live
>   events.

work around for `.live()` event propagation issues.
nodes created dynamically will not receive the event until after their parent has received it.
this will cause funkyness and stopPropagation and preventDefault will not solve this issue.
To Fix: add the lines

```
if(event.target != this){
return true;
}
```

to the top of the parent nodes event handler. this will stop the parent event from firing when the event is actually addressed to a child node, and (unlike return false) will propagate the event to the intended node.

Comment: It works when I use the e.stopImmediatePropagation. Have a look at InfernalBadger answer.