# jquery-live or stopPropagation?

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="button" class="pop_up" value="pop_up" />
<input type="button" class="go_back" value="go_back" />

<div id="contents"></div>

<script>

$(".pop_up").live("click", function (e) {
    var seq = $(this).val()
    alert(seq);
}); // #1  

$(".go_back").live("click", function (e) {
    $("#contents").load("test.php");
}); // #2

</script>
```

Now,

according to times of click #2, pop up #1 Alert window.

Could anyone let me know how to stop event bubbling of #2

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to have an indicator if the #1 event was triggered, and process the #2 function only if if the #1 event was not triggered.

```
$(".pop_up").live("click",function(e)
{
     $(this).data('pop_up_click', true); // set 'pop_up_click' property to the element
     // #1 var seq=$(this).val() alert(seq);
}); 
$(".go_back").live("click", function(e)
{
    if(!$(this).data('pop_up_click'))    // execute something  only if there is no 'pop_up_click' property 
       // #2 $("#contents").load( "test.php" );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In reference to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632381/jquery-stop-event-bubbling-with-live), this *MAY* work.

```
$(".go_back").live("click", function(e) {   // #2
    $("#contents").load("test.php");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
});
```

The real solution, if possible, would be to use `.bind()`, provided you don't need the benefits of `.live()` directly.

Comment: You cannot stop propagation of live events. They have already bubbled to the top.

Comment: Thank you but i still have same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer. This may or may not be helpful so I apologise!